# is contextual typing just another term for type Inference?

Tags: typescript

I am reading a lot on TypeScript docs right now, and noticed that some authors will say *contextual typing* and others will say *type inference*. Some will refer to them in the same light (it appears they are just not being consistent with the choice of terms). Once I am sure they are the same thing I will read something that give the impression they are not.

At this point it almost feels like some of the authors themselves are not sure. One thing I do know is I am not sure. Can someone please clear this up.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contextual typing is a *subset* of type inference. See [Contextual Typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) in the documentation:

> **Contextual Typing**
>
> Type inference also works in “the other direction” in some cases in TypeScript. This is known as “contextual typing”. Contextual typing occurs when the type of an expression is implied by its location. For example:
>
> ```
> window.onmousedown = function(mouseEvent) {
>    console.log(mouseEvent.button);   //<- OK
>    console.log(mouseEvent.kangaroo); //<- Error!
> };
> ```
>
> Here, the Typescript type checker used the type of the `Window.onmousedown` function to infer the type of the function expression on the right hand side of the assignment. When it did so, it was able to infer the type of the `mouseEvent` parameter, which does contain a `button` property, but not a `kangaroo` property.

So rather than inferring the type of a variable by what's assigned to it, contextual typing is inferring the type of a variable by where it is.

---

That entire page is probably worth a good read.

Comment: "Contextual typing is a subset of type inference" resolved it in my head, thank you.